# Evaluating variables in a string in bash

Tags: bash

The last line in this script won't work as I expect:

```bash
myfile="afile.txt"
mycmd='cat $myfile'
eval $mycmd
echo eval $mycmd
```

Here `echo eval $mycmd` prints `eval cat $myfile`.
How can I print `eval cat afile.txt`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Let's take things step by step:

When you do this:

```
mycmd='cat $myfile'
```

You prevent the shell from interpolating `$myfile`. Thus:

```
$ echo $mycmd
cat $myfile
```

If you want to allow the interpolation, you can use double quotes:

```
$ mycmd="echo $myfile"  #Double quotes!
$ echo "$mycmd"
cat afile.txt
```

This, of course, *freezes* the interpretation of `$mycmd` when you do an `eval`.

```
$ myfile="afile.txt"
$ mycmd="echo $myfile"
$ echo $mycmd
cat afile.txt
$ eval $mycmd   #Prints out afile.txt
$ myfile=bfile.txt
$ eval $mycmd   #Still prints out afile.txt and not bfile.txt
```

Compare this to:

```
$ myfile="afile.txt"
$ mycmd='cat $myfile'   #Single quotes hide $myfile from the shell
echo $mycmd
cat $myfile             #Shell didn't change "$myfile", so it prints as a literal
$ eval $mycmd           #Prints out afile.txt
$ myfile=bfile.txt
$ eval $mycmd           #Now prints out bfile.txt
```

What you probably want to do is to evaluate the `$mycmd` in an echo statement when you echo it:

```
$ echo $(eval "echo $mycmd")
$ cat afile.txt
$ myfile=bfile.txt
$ echo $(eval "echo $mycmd")
cat bfile.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work for: grep fatal `find /var/log/ -name 'current'

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. From `mycmd='cat $myfile'` how do we get a string with `cat thevalueofmyfile`?!

Answer (score 14):

You can write:

```
eval echo eval $mycmd
```

or a bit more robust:

```
eval echo eval "$mycmd"
```

That said, I'd recommend avoiding `eval` whenever possible; it tends to be very fragile, because there are many complicated steps in Bash command-line processing, and use of `eval` typically means you will perform those steps more than once. It's hard to keep track of what's really going on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to eval the echo, rather than the other way around:

```
eval echo "eval $mycmd"
```

or

```
eval echo eval "$mycmd"
```

I think the former is preferable, but at least quote the variable expansion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash, the better way to do it is to use arrays:

```
myfile="afile.txt"
mycmd=(cat "$myfile")
echo "${mycmd[@]}"
"${mycmd[@]}"
```