# Escaped quotes in string are re-escaped

Tags: bash, quotes, double-quotes, quote, quoting

I currently have a bash script where I want to separate the command to be executed from the execution itself (for readability purposes):

```
set -x
MAIN_COMMAND="mysql -u root \"select 1 from dual;\""
...
MAIN_RESULT=$($MAIN_COMMAND 2>&1)
```

when executing the command, I get the following debug output:

> ++mysql -u root '"select' 1 from 'dual;"'

obviously, there's something wrong with the way I escaped the string, but I can't pinpoint it.

furthermore the output redirection does not get concatenated to the main command.

Comment: @tripleee: I was searching for an exact duplicate involving `mysql` in a variable. Thought it be useful.

Comment: Do `cmd=(mysql -u root "select 1 from dual;"); result=$( "${cmd[@]}" 2>&1)`

Comment: the extra quoting you are seeing is just the way the shell "normalizes" its output. Yes, it makes it hard to understand where the problem is, but if you're certain  you're quoting is correct inside you script, then you can assume what is being displayed is correct (sorry I can't explain it logically, but there is a logical explanation ;-) ). To convince yourself this is the case, do some experimenting on the command with with `set -x` active. Good luck.

Comment: @Inian your duplicated mark do not include the origin of the question

Comment: @PaulRM: Agreed but the context is the same

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try with:

```
set -x
MAIN_COMMAND="mysql -u root \"select 1 from dual;\""
MAIN_RESULT=$("$MAIN_COMMAND" 2>&1)
```

But, this only fix the escape part,

to the complete result, I use something like:

```
 set -x
 MAIN_COMMAND="MYSQL_PWD=dbpass /usr/bin/mysql -u dbuser dbname <<< \"select 1 from dual;\""
 MAIN_RESULT=$(eval "$MAIN_COMMAND" 2>&1)
```

Comment: I end up with: mysql command not found...

Comment: Yes, that part is an expected result.
Too fix complety set -x
MAIN_COMMAND="MYSQL_PWD=dbpass /usr/bin/mysql -u dbuser dbname <<< \"select 1 from dual;\""
MAIN_RESULT=$(eval "$MAIN_COMMAND" 2>&1)

Comment: Yes thanks. it also close to the solution I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219262/evaluating-variables-in-a-string