# How to use an environment variable in an AWS CLI command

Tags: aws-cli

I run this command and it works :

`` aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`vpc-#########`]|[].LoadBalancerName' --region us-east-2 ``

If I try and use an environemnt variable it does not work :

`` aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`$VPC_ID`]|[].LoadBalancerName' --region us-east-2 ``

I know that VPC_ID is valid  - echo $VPC_ID  returns the correct value

What am I not seeing?

Thanks!!!!!

---

I also tried this command with the same results :

This works fine :
`` aws elb describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Instances[?InstanceId==`i-0############`]].[LoadBalancerName]' --region us-east-2 ``

This returns nothing : 
`aws elb describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Instances[?InstanceId=="$InstanceID"]].[LoadBalancerName]' --region us-east-2`

I know that the environment variable $InstanceID is populated and correct - I perform an echo $InstanceID and get the correct ID output.

Comment: Probably the single quotes around the variable.  Remove them or maybe change them to double quotes and see what happens.

Comment: Tried it and it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!!

The environment variable need to be in brackets - { }

This works -

`aws elb describe-load-balancers --output text --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Instances[?InstanceId=='${InstanceID}']].LoadBalancerName" --region us-east-2`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this using the following:

```
export MY_VPC_ID=vpc-1234
echo 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`$MY_VPC_ID`]|[].LoadBalancerName'
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`$MY_VPC_ID`]|[].LoadBalancerName
```

I believe this has to do with how bash interprets quotes as shown in this other post
[Evaluating variables in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219262/evaluating-variables-in-a-string)

Can you try using this?

```
echo "LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==\"$MY_VPC_ID\"]|[].LoadBalancerName"
```

**OUTPUT**:
`LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId=="vpc-1234"]|[].LoadBalancerName`

Comment: I also tried this and it does not work. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: What in particular are you looking for? I put that option in and a ton of info was returned.

Comment: Did it have the query params we sent? Was the environment variable interpreted?

Comment: No - the environment variable was not interpreted.